# what does /path/to refer to in entering a cron job

Tags: cron

I want to create a cron job which will run every 5 minutes. I have understood the concept of setting the condition of 'every five minutes' from a previous answer on the same topic. However, i do not understand the part where it says /path/to command. i have the format for every 5 minutes as `*/5 * * * *` and i have set root as the user. The job i want to be have run every 5 minutes is executed by the following command

```
snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq  172.16.1.210 \
      .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2 > /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
```

How can i add this cron job properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/path/to/command` is the the path to the bin file of your command `snmpbulkwalk`. When you run `snmpbulkwalk`, you're actually running its binary file which is located probably in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. To find out what this path is, run `which snmpbulkwalk`. Let's say this returns `/usr/bin/snmpbulkwalk`. Therefore, your `cronjob` would be:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq  172.16.1.210 .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2 > /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
```

Comment: Ah now I see what he means... Ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to know how to setup this cronjob. Just hit

```
 crontab -e
```

Then choose your favorite editor (for me that's vim) copy and paste the line above and make sure it is followed by a white line. Then save it (in vim you hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and  type `:wq`. Then you can check whether it is in the cron file by typing:

```
crontab -l
```

If am not mistaken you can check in which folder your cron job starts by adding a cron job like:

```
* * * * * env > env-output.txt
```

and then read the env-output.txt file after a few minutes. This file will contain your path and all that sort of stuff. But maybe your command might work out of the box.